# ssh: connect to host [ip] port 22: No route to host

Tags: networking, server, ssh, network-manager, vpn

The VPN connection was successful, but:

```
$ ssh -X -l cristic 192.168.1.40
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.40 port 22: No route to host
```

It may be of importance that I am abroad, visiting a friend, and using a different internet provider than usual.
Please help. I am pretty new to linux and the IT guy is on vacation.

Comment: Please Edit your question and add (formatted with '`{}`') the results of `ip route`.

Comment: Are you actually away from your server right now, and entering the command `ssh -X -l cristic 192.168.1.40`

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the reply!

```
$ ip route 
default dev ppp0 proto static 
192.168.1.145 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.153 
192.168.10.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.106 metric 9
193.228.153.48 via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 proto static 
193.228.153.48 via 192.168.10.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.10.106
```

However, at the suggestion of a friend, I previously changed my IP in the LAN settings of my router (192.168.10.1, instead of 192.168.1.1) and now everything works just fine.